# HP Envy-4500-all-in-one Printer Error

Tags: printer, ink, hp-envy

I don't know if this is the right site to post this question at, but I'll ask it anyways. I have a HP Envy 4500 all-in-one printer that keeps telling me: **"The following ink Cartridge(s) must be replaced."** when I just replaced my old PS Products black ink cartridge with a brand new PS Products black ink cartridge.

Comment: The new cartridge could be faulty, or not installed correctly. Also, have you tried a genuine HP cartridge?

Comment: @hdhondt Yes, it could be faulty. I'm pretty sure i installed it incorrectly. I got the same result after many attempts of pulling out and re-inserting the ink cartridge. But I have not tried a genuine HP ink cartridge.